# Question about basis (or complete sets) in the function space

Tags: laplace-transform, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

My language of mathematics can be sloppy as I have a physics background.

The Fourier transformable functions $f(x)$ (which obeys absolute integrability condition $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx<\infty$) can be decomposed as $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(k)e^{ikx}dk\tag{1}$$ which implies that for such functions $f(x)$, the set $\{e^{ikx}\}$ where $k$ varies continuously over $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ forms a complete set. Similarly functions $g(x)$ which are Laplace transformable can be written as $$g(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\tilde{g}(s)e^{-st}ds.\tag{2}$$

Does it not mean that the set $\{e^{-st}\}$ where $s$ varies continuously over $0$ to $+\infty$ also form a complete set for the functions $g(x)$?

Comment: “My language of mathematics can be sloppy as I have a physics background.”—precisely why I had to stop taking physics courses in grad school (It is still a good question though)

Comment: Actually what you say about the Fourier transform is not so; in fact the function $e^t$ is not a "fourier transformable" function. (Or if it is, you need to say exactly what  you mean by "fourier tranformable".) Who told you that a Laplace transformable function has a representation like that? This is news to me...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can we not think of Eq. (2) as the function $g(t)$ being decomposed into the set of functions $e^{-st}$? Eq. (2) is the very definition of Laplace's transform. Right?

Comment: First, Eq. (1) is _not_ true assuming just $\int|f|<\infty$. Yes, the second equation is the definition of the Laplace transform. It's the Laplace transform _of_ $\tilde g$. And yes, it does say that in some sense the functions $e^{st}$ span the space of Laplace transforms. The problem is that you said the equation applied to "Laplace transformable" functions $g$. If "Laplace transformable" means anything it means "has a Laplace transform". In that equation $g$ _is_ a Laplace transform; "is a Laplace transform" and "has a Laplace transform" are totally different conditions

Comment: And no, the functions $e^{ikt}$ simply do _not_ form a complete set. At least not in any space that I can think of - actually "form a complete set" is meaningless by itself. _What_ _space_ are you claiming they form a complete set _in_?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Is Eq. (2) correct?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $L^2$.

Comment: I already agreed it's the definition of the Laplace transform of $\tilde g$. What's not correct is claiming it says anything about the space of "Laplace tranformable" functions. _Unless_ you mean something very different from what one naturally assumes you mean by "Laplae trandformable"/

Comment: $L^2$, fine. The functions $e^{ikt}$ are not even _in_ $L^2$, so they certainly cannot form a complete set in $L^2$.

Comment: I think I should delete this ask a fresh question, @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: If you do, try to avoid non-standard undefined terminology like "Laplace transformable" - if you use that phrase provide a _definition_ so we don't have to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has said that (s)he is going to delete the question - since that hasn't happened yet, there may as well be an answer for the record:

None of this makes much sense, as far as I can see: The question asks something about the Laplace transform, by analogy with the Fourier transform, but the previous facts about the Fourier transform are simply not so.

First, assuming just $\int|f(t)|\,dt<\infty$ does *not* imply that $f$ has a representation $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(k)e^{ikx}dk.$$That would be true if $\int|f|<\infty$ *and* $\int|\hat f|<\infty$.

Does this imply that the functions $e^{ikt}$ form a "complete set"? The OP clarified in a comment that here "complete set" means "complete set in $L^2$". The functions $e^{ikt}$ are certainly *not* a complete set in $L^2$, since they're obviously not even *elements* of $L^2$ to begin with.

Now we come to the question about "Laplace transformable"  functions. My best guess, neither confirmed nor denied by the OP, is that saying $g$ is Laplace tranformable means that $g$ has a Laplace transform. If so then saying $g$ is Laplace transformable does *not* say that $$g(s)=\int_0^\infty\tilde g(t)e^{-st}\,dt;$$(or if it does this is news to me) - that says that $g$ *is* a Laplace tranform (in particular it is the Laplace transform of $\tilde g$), not that $g$ *has* a Laplace transform.

(No, come to think of it saying $g$ has a Laplace transform clearly does not imply $g$ *is* a Laplace transform. For example, under minimal growth conditions in $h$, if $g=\mathcal L\{h\}$ then $g$ is continuous.)